# Converting the response from dataproc api list_jobs gcp python sdk response to dict/json

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to find a way to convert the dataproc.list_jobs response to a python dict or json without any luck. There have been some ways to convert these grpc messages which comes as the responses to a dict but none of these worked with this one.

here is the sdk function link: [DataProc List Jobs](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/dataproc/latest/google.cloud.dataproc_v1.services.job_controller.JobControllerClient#google_cloud_dataproc_v1_services_job_controller_JobControllerClient_list_jobs)

here is the code:

```
for job_response in client.list_jobs(project_id=self.project_id, region=region.get(constants.NAME_KEY)): 
    job = MessageToDict(job_response) # throws an error saying descriptor not found
    job = job_response._properties # Which is available in some other related responses, but not this one
    job = job_response.to_api_repr() # Which is available in some other related response objects, but not this one. So doesn't work here.
    job = job_response.__class__.to_json(job_response) # Which is available in some other related response objects, but not this one. So doesn't work here.
```

I am at a loss here. I can manually get the fields and create a dictionary myself. But that's not something I want.